# Is there a way to change the gear size of a existing scaled application on Openshift without recreating it?

Tags: openshift

Would have thought there would be a easier way to change the gear size of a existing scaled application in OpenShift but I can't seem to find a way to do it through the command line with rhc or the web console.

I can change the storage size but not the gear size.

Seems I have to delete and recreate the app to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to directly affect the size of the gear that your application is running on, however, you can easily copy it to another gear and specify the size that you want to use using the `rhc app create <name> --from-app <app name> --gear-size SIZE` command